# Can I make my Angular app compatible across all versions of IE?

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, angular6

I would like to make my Angular 6 application compatible across IE version 7-11. I have no idea if this is possible. I followed some advice from another post about the polyfills file, but had no luck.

My polyfils looks like:

```
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
 import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
 import 'core-js/es6/object';
 import 'core-js/es6/function';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
 import 'core-js/es6/number';
 import 'core-js/es6/math';
 import 'core-js/es6/string';
 import 'core-js/es6/date';
 import 'core-js/es6/array';
 import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
 import 'core-js/es6/map';
 import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
 import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
// import 'core-js/es6/reflect';


/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';


/**
 * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`
 * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
 * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
 **/
// import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

/**
 * By default, zone.js will patch all possible macroTask and DomEvents
 * user can disable parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch by setting following flags
 */

 // (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
 // (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
 // (window as any).__zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames

 /*
 * in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
 * with the following flag, it will bypass `zone.js` patch for IE/Edge
 */
// (window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;

/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
```

As of now I get a bunch of errors in all version of IE except of IE 11. 
For example:

```
Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'bind' on the 3rd line here
var jsonpArray = window["webpackJsonp"] = window["webpackJsonp"] || [];
    var oldJsonpFunction = jsonpArray.push.bind(jsonpArray);
    jsonpArray.push = webpackJsonpCallback;
    jsonpArray = jsonpArray.slice();


Error: Expected identifier, string or number one the resolvePromise line
var value = zone.run(delegate, undefined, isFinallyPromise && delegate !== forwardRejection && delegate !== forwardResolution ?
                    [] :
                    [parentPromiseValue]);
                resolvePromise(chainPromise, true, value);
            }
```

I am not sure if there is anything I can do, but I would appreciate any advice. If you need anymore information about my app, please let me know.

Comment: This is a bit hard to answer as there is not a magic bullet I am aware of if the polyfills did not solve all of your compatibility issues I would start by googling the errors with the browser version and see if they can be tackled one by one. If Googling does not help, posting with the *specific* error may yield you some responses as to what the specific problem is and if there is a realistic workaround.

Comment: There are a lot of errors in vendro.js and runtime.js. I will post a few of them above. The polyfills are supposed to help with addressing different versions correct? I wasn't sure if that was true or not.

Comment: Yes, these polyfills are meant to help out of the box getting your application to work on the different versions of your browsers, but they do not handle all of the numerous javascript, css, html intricacies that you may have written or introduced with packages that are not supported on legacy browsers. Though I believe it does not state about anything before IE9.

I believe each one of those errors is going to require some individual research as to how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [browser support](https://v6.angular.io/guide/browser-support) in Angular 6 official documentation, Angular 6 only supports 
IE 9-11. So I think we're not able to support Angular 6 in IE < 9.

To support in IE 9-11, you could also uncomment `import 'core-js/es6/reflect';` and `import 'web-animations-js';`. The easy way is just to replace all `// import` with `import` in **polyfill.ts**. After that, you need to install some packages with npm:

```
npm install --save classlist.js
npm install --save web-animations-js
```

Finally, add the meta tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` in your **index.html**.

Besides, if your code contains more code that is not supported in IE then you have to find the polyfill and import it yourself.

Comment: I had the meta tag but there was a typo. so with your post and another post I was able to get things up and going. thanks!!